# how to get args to constructor at extjs?

Tags: javascript, extjs, arguments

I have a some class

```
AddOrgWindowUI = Ext.extend(Ext.Window, {
title: 'form',
width: 400,
height: 198,
layout: 'form',
padding: 5,
initComponent: function() {
    this.items = [
        {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'parapapa',
            anchor: '95%',
            value: m,
            emptyText: 'perapapa'
        }
    ];
    AddOrgWindowUI.superclass.initComponent.call(this);
}});
```

when I create an object `var AddOrgWindowForm = new AddOrgWindowUI('aaa');` I want to get arg ('aaa') to my new form value (value m). How get it?
Im trying `initComponent: function(m) {` and thats not working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `initComponent` function is called internally on one of the base classes of `Ext.Window`. You shouldn't try to call it directly. That is why it won't handle your own parameters.

So I recommend you to use the standard form parameters when [extending ExtJS classes](http://www.sencha.com/learn/Manual:Component:Extending_Ext_Components).

**It is as simple as initializing the object with the property or methods you want to override (or insert in case the property is not in there already). And then just using the `this` keyword to access them.**

This is possible because for every `Ext.Component` and its subclasses, the first parameter passed to the constructor should be an object, and every member in that object will be copied to the new object constructed. And most ExtJS classes extend directly or indirectly from `Ext.Component`, and you are extending from `Ext.Window` which extends from `Ext.Component` too.

Here you have your example fixed:

```
var AddOrgWindowUI = Ext.extend(Ext.Window, {
    title: 'form',
    width: 400,
    height: 198,
    layout: 'form',
    padding: 5,

    initComponent: function() {
        this.items = [
            {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                fieldLabel: 'parapapa',
                anchor: '95%',
                value: this.initialValue,
                emptyText: 'perapapa'
            }
        ];
        AddOrgWindowUI.superclass.initComponent.call(this);
    }
});

function test() {
    var AddOrgWindowForm = new AddOrgWindowUI({initialValue:'aaa'});
    AddOrgWindowForm.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

pass m as an arg of initComponent:

edit:

```
AddOrgWindowUI = function(input) {
    var m = input;
    return Ext.extend(Ext.Window, {
        title: 'form',
        width: 400,
        height: 198,
        layout: 'form',
        padding: 5,
        initComponent: function() {
            this.items = [
        {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'parapapa',
            anchor: '95%',
            value: m,
            emptyText: 'perapapa'
        }
    ];
            AddOrgWindowUI.superclass.initComponent.call(this);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: thx, but how to declare a new object?
var AddOrgWindowForm = new AddOrgWindowUI.initComponent('aaa'); - doesnt work.

Comment: it doesnt work too :( try it. Firebug say - "AddOrgWindowUI.initComponent is not a function"

Comment: Doing it this way you loose the ability to pass in any other configuration items to the constructor.